# set x:string value from C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-runtime

In my app.xaml I have this

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Application-specific resources -->

    <x:String x:Key="AppName">My Application</x:String>

</Application.Resources>
```

But actually I already set it in my constant code as example like this.

```
public const string AppName = "Test App";
```

Can I set AppName from app.xaml to that constant? I know it simpler to just edit app.xaml. But I have more scenario for this.

Answer (score -1):

The meaning of const in C# syntax means you won't be able to change it. The const means that the compiler will replace any usage of that variable with the value. basically meaning that after the compile time, no chance of changing. 
If that was not a const then you could use the ResourceManager to get the value and set the variable with it.

The Resources of Xaml can be accessed using the key like this

```
 this.Resources["AppName"]
```

But Application.Resources is not designed for storing string values. Instead normal .Net Resources should be used. If you are using Visual Studio, then You can achieve this easily by adding a Resource file to the project in Visual Studio. If you call the resource file let's say 'MyValues.resx' then visual Studio will build and maintain a generated class called MyValues for you. If you open that and simply add a string to it, calling it let's say 'MyApplicationTitle' then, simply in  your C# code you can use it like this

```
public static string AppName = MyValues.MyApplicationTitle
```

Comment: what if is not a const? So I need to change it to static. I just change that AppName for once in my app...

Comment: I have to do a bit of guessing on what you try to do. The Application.Resources is usually used to define things like Background in the Xaml application. I update my answer to cover how to store strings in Resources and use them in code

Comment: I know how to use resx. What I mean is how the app.xaml x:string get value from the C# code behind it? Because in app.xaml I can't bind it

Comment: Is your application building and running? The namespace x: in the App.Xaml file is by default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' where the String element should be invalid.